# Eclipse 4.9 STS 4 very slow and often get stuck

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I saw several similar questions in StackOverflow but no-one specific about STS 4 where I'm having a big problem working with my project.
The IDE is almost unusable,most of the time it is stuck: during autocomplete, during saving, many times also during editing a simple .java file.

I followed many tricks trying to improve Eclipse performances but noone solved my problem.

I added these lines in config.ini:

```
-Xverify:none
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

I disabled many label decorations:

[image]
[image]
[image]

My computer is:

```
CPU Intel I6700-K
RAM: 32GB
HDD: SSD M2 Samsung 970 EVO
Windows 10 professional
```

I tried to take a look if the CPU is overloaded when STS becomes unresponsive, but from this image it seems not:

[image]

At some point I saw a quite high thread count on java process (even if I don't know if that is a problem):

[image]

When, after few minutes, I kill STS I've this error:

[image]

I already tried to:

1. format my pc and reinstall Windows 10 pro from scratch
2. install STS 4 from scratch
3. create a new worspace and import sources without any previous configuration

To complete the scenario these are some logs from Eclipse:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:45:50.345
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:46:29.411
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {CONTENT | FINE GRAINED | PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:46:29.693
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:46:38.688
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:46:41.184
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {CONTENT | FINE GRAINED | PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:46:41.791
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:46:46.642
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:46:56.143
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:47:13.019
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:47:15.209
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:47:31.003
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:47:34.064
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {CONTENT | FINE GRAINED | PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:47:34.355
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:47:34.492
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:05.543
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:05.944
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:17.486
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {CONTENT | FINE GRAINED | PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:17.810
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:38.906
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {CONTENT | FINE GRAINED | PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:39.237
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:44.314
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:48:44.640
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:03.502
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:06.597
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:08.697
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:11.597
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:14.024
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:19.413
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:21.825
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:24.919
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:27.348
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:30.490
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:33.414
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:49:34.114
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {CONTENT | FINE GRAINED | PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:49:34.706
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:37.749
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:49:41.344
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CHILDREN | CONTENT}
        src/main/java[*]: {CHILDREN}
            cloud.test.server.model.medical.exams[*]: {CHILDREN}
                [Working copy] EyeExam.java[*]: {CONTENT | FINE GRAINED | PRIMARY RESOURCE}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]]

!ENTRY org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 1 0 2018-10-26 16:49:41.870
!MESSAGE changeEvent = org.eclipse.jdt.core.ElementChangedEvent[source=Java Model[*]: {CHILDREN}
    test-server[*]: {CONTENT}
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/src)[*]
        ResourceDelta(/test-server/target)[*]]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:46.767
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:168)
    at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2018-10-26 16:49:58.720
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at
```

Could you give me some advice to solve this huge problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you can try going here:

http://download.eclipse.org/lsp4e/releases/latest/
and
http://download.eclipse.org/lsp4j/updates/releases/

and get the latest jars and see if that helps, it cleared it up for me. You could also check out the snapshot versions. As you said this issue has been reported in several places and there are defects for them for eclipse already.

Me:

Spring Tool Suite 4

Version: 4.0.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201810300749

Answer (score 0):

> I had same issues. To resolve these issues I added one jar `tools.jar` at location `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib`. This jar was missing for me. Now it working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, clearly mentioned in the "[Eclipse 4.17 - New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/)" (2020-09 release)

> Windows 10 users: [Windows 10 Defender significantly slows down Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548443), reason being Windows 10 Defender scanning the JAR files.
>
> The problem has been [reported to Microsoft here](https://aka.ms/AA67uk5).
>
> Until then, a workaround to this problem is to add Eclipse root directory to Windows 10 Defender's exclusion list, detailed steps [are shared here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548443#c28).